# How can you get Eclipse CDT to understand MSPGCC (MSP430) includes?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, msp430

I'm using Eclipse and CDT to work with the mspgcc compiler, it compiles fine, but the code view highlights all my special function registers as unresolved.

I've made a C project where the compiler is "msp430-gcc -mmcu=msp430x2012", and that's set to look for includes in /usr/msp430/include/. I've set the linker to "msp430-gcc -mmcu=msp430x2012", and that's set to look fo libraries in /usr/msp430/lib/. I've set the assembler to "msp430-as". I've told eclipse it's making an elf and I've disabled automatic includes discovery to not find the i686 libraries on my linux box (stupid eclipse!).

Here's the code:

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <signal.h> //for interrupts

#define RED 1
#define GREEN   64
#define S2VAL   8

void init(void);

int main(void) {
  init();       //Setup Device

  P1OUT = GREEN;    //start with a green LED

  _BIS_SR(LPM4_bits);   //Go into Low power mode 4, main stops here

  return(1);        //never reached, surpresses compiler warning
}

interrupt (PORT1_VECTOR) S1ServiceRoutine(void) {
  //we wake the MCU here

  if (RED & P1IN) {
    P1OUT = GREEN;
  } else {
    P1OUT = RED;
  }

  P1IFG = 0;    //clear the interrupt flag or we immidiately go again

  //we resume LPM4 here thanks to the RETI instruction
}

void init(void) {
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;     // Stop WDT
  /*Halt the watchdog timer

  P1DIR = ~S2VAL;       //Set LED pins as outputs and S2 as input

  P1IES = S2VAL;        //interrupt on High to Low
  P1IE = S2VAL;         //enable interrupt for S1 only
  WRITE_SR(GIE);        //enable maskable interrupts
}
```

All the variables defines in the mspgcc includes such as P1OUT and WDTCTL show up in the problems box as "not resolved", but remember it builds just fine. I've even tried explicitly including the header file for my chip (normally msp430-gcc does this via msp430.h and the -mmcu option).

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue by explicitly including the msp430g2553.h file

```
#include <msp430g2553.h>
```

Comment: I did the same although I put it within a `#ifndef COMPILING` or something like that. Then in my Makefile I added `-DCOMPILING` to the CFLAGS. Note though that I do not use Eclipse but Vim with youcompleteme plugin but I asume that Eclipse is smart enough to handle something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by following the instructions [here](http://www.43oh.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/MSP430_MSPGCC_Eclipse_gdb.pdf)